# Javascript plugin to draw markers, lines, and shapes on a latitude/longitude grid for offline use?

Tags: javascript, cordova, dictionary, gis, offline

I am attempting to make a simple PhoneGap app that will allow a user to input lat/long points and bearings and calculate their estimated intersection, along with a measure of error. I would like to display the lines, intersection, and an error elipsoid on a map or at least a grid of latitude and longitude lines, so the user can visualize the accuracy of the point. The tricky part is that this will be used for wildlife tracking in areas where the user may not have cell service. Is there some sort of Javascript plugin that will make a lat/long grid available for me to draw georeferenced lines and shapes on? I would love to use something like the Google Maps API, but that clearly won't work for offline use. I've Googled quite a bit, but I'm not sure where to start with this or if it's even feasible at all.

This program is similar to what I'm trying to achieve: http://www.locateiii.com/

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) with [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) tiles prepared by [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/). Simple and works well with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use d3.js and http://code.google.com/p/gmapcatcher/ something like this where you can keep the google maps offline. If that's not feasible you can always us D3 with a svg of the map.